# how to draw adjustable Right Angle Using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, angle

I am trying to Draw a Right Angle using Rectangles.

My Problem is instead of Using two Rectangles to Draw the Adjustable Right Angle,I want to use a Exact Right Angle as in this Image

[image: RightAngle]

I am using the Below code to add the Rectangle using fabric.js

```
  addRect = () => {
     this.canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
        left: this.canvas.width / 2,
        top: this.canvas.height / 2,
        fill: '#ffa726',
        width: 100,
        centeredRotation: true,
        height: 100,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
       strokeWidth: 0
                             }));
            }
```

Kindly Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `Rect` to get just a right angle, but you can use a `Polyline`. Here's an example:

```
const points = [
  {x: 5, y: 15},
  {x: 95, y: 15},
  {x: 95, y: 85},
]
const options = {
  strokeWidth: 20,
  stroke: 'orange',
  fill: null,
  strokeLineJoin: 'miter',
  strokeLineCap: 'butt'
}
const rightAngle = new fabric.Polyline(points, options)
canvas.add(rightAngle)
```

If you want to interactively adjust the points, you could adapt the code from the [custom controls example](http://fabricjs.com/custom-controls-polygon) on the Fabric.js site (Polygon and Polyline are similar).